# SQL count distinct values appearing in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, unpivot

i want to count distinct values and report their occurrences in SQL. The thing is i need to count occurrences on different columns and then report, for each column, the number of occurrences per value. So, say i have data like this from a table called Result :

| Id | OwnerId | PilotId | CoachId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| C | 3 | 1 | 3 |

Then my result should be :

| Id | Owner | Pilot | Coach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 3 |

I tried using COUNT function with unions to get each result individually and it works. But i want to have the results on the same row **per Id**. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I don't get the `0` values.

Comment: That's if the ID never appears in a specific column from the input data. For example, 1 and 2 never appear in column "CoachId", hence 0.

Comment: But a value is always going to appear at least once, @rucquoy if it's in the table. In your result set, `PilotID` `1` appears once, yet you have a count of `0` for it?

Comment: What are the `Id` in the second column coming from and what is the relation between the  columns in the first table (the ones with `Id` suffix) with the columns in the result table?

Comment: That's my bad, the question is not well structured. Say that my input data is a table having an ID and 3 Foreign keys (OwnerId, PilotId, CoachId). Then i wish to have, for each distinct values of these foreign key, their occurrences per column. (So, for each FK value, i should have 3 counts : the # of times it appears as an OwnerId, the # of times it appears as aPilotId and the # of times it appears as a CoachId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to unpivot the columns to rows, then count the occurences of each value. You can do:

```
select v.id,
    sum(case when v.col = 'owner' then 1 else 0 end) owner,
    sum(case when v.col = 'pilot' then 1 else 0 end) pilot,
    sum(case when v.col = 'coach' then 1 else 0 end) coach
from mytable t
cross apply (values (t.ownerid, 'owner'), (t.pilotid, 'pilot'), (t.coachid, 'coach')) as v(id, col)
group by v.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c47970f97e5b50bdb7fe5eb7b4babc3)**:

```
id | owner | pilot | coach
-: | ----: | ----: | ----:
 1 |     1 |     1 |     0
 2 |     1 |     2 |     0
 3 |     1 |     0 |     3
```

Comment: Yes, that appears to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Ooooooooooo, that's sweet. Took less than a second to run on a table with 700k+ rows. I didn't even know what cross apply is, i still have a lot to learn i guess. Thanks for your answer sir !

Answer (score 0):

The same using basic `SQL` commands. assured to work on every DBMS:

```
SELECT 
  ids.id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ro.ownerid = ids.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Owner,
  SUM(CASE WHEN po.pilotid = ids.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pilot,
  SUM(CASE WHEN co.coachid = ids.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Coach
FROM (
  SELECT ownerID AS id FROM result UNION
  SELECT pilotID FROM result UNION
  SELECT coachID FROM result  
) ids
  LEFT JOIN result ro ON ids.id = ro.ownerid
  LEFT JOIN result po ON ids.id = po.pilotid
  LEFT JOIN result co ON ids.id = co.coachid
GROUP BY ids.id
```

Here in [SQLFiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55bf9e/13)